# Class for the sake of readability

Tags: java, oop

I have a method that returns a list of booleans,
this list happens to represent successful pings to ips that were sent as an argument:

```
List<Boolean> testPing (List<String> ips) {
  method logic....
  loop on all ips      
  (if ips.get(i) pings successfully then resultList.add(true) 
    else add false..)
}
```

My problem is that I am using this return list later in couple of methods
and this is not very clear when you read the method, what is that list of booleans
So the question is, will it be right to wrap it in a class like - PingResults for the sake of readability?
However, this class won't have anything other than a single list property and get/set

Comment: In which class is `testPing()` currently sitting?  If you plan to use it a more general way, then you can create a helper class and maybe turn it into a `static` helper method.

Comment: Can't you just name the list variable something like `pingResultsList`?

Comment: @BadCash I can, though it won't solve my problem that the code is unreadable, for example - I have a something like, List<Callable<List<Boolean>>> and it is not very clear what is the purpose of this boolean list that will be returned

Answer (score 5):

I'd make a PingResult class that contain the target ip, the result and maybe a timestamp

Answer (score 4):

I would return a Map of results. Something like

```
Map<String, PingResult> testPing (List<String> ips) {
    return ips.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(ip -> ip, PingResult::new));
}
```

By using a custom `PingResult` class you can add information like timing (how long it took to ping)

Comment: you can even define an IP class instead of using strings for IPs

Comment: you may want to fix your first sentence "I would result a Map of results".

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a class, but you can also return `Map<String, Boolean>` which maps your string ip to your boolean result in which way a class is unnecessary and it's still pretty readable.